# EMS connection works with "tcp" but not "tibjmsnaming"

Tags: jms, tibco-ems

I was given a Tibco EMS connection URL "tibjmsnaming://xx.xx.xx.xxx:7551,tibjmsnaming://xx.xx.xx.xxx:7551" (IP address masked here). When I tried to connect using JMS like this:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory("tibjmsnaming://xx.xx.xx.xxx:7551,tibjmsnaming://xx.xx.xx.xxx:7551");
Connection connection = factory.createConnection("test", "abcd");
```

I got the exception:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Protocol not supported
```

However, if I change "tibjmsnaming" to "tcp" as shown below, the connection will be successful.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory("tcp://xx.xx.xx.xxx:7551,tcp://xx.xx.xx.xxx:7551");
Connection connection = factory.createConnection("test", "abcd");
```

Since I can connect with "tcp", I can probably leave it like that. But I would like to know whether I am missing out something when changing from "tibjmsnaming" to "tcp" (for example, in terms of sacrificing security).

Answer (score 2):

The "tcp://" or "ssl://" prefix are the proper way to connect to the JMS function of a TIBCO EMS server.  So if you use TibjmsConnectionFactory, that is correct.

The alternative way in JMS, however, is to a JMS ConnectionFactory by name from a JNDI implementation. And to access the JNDI repository of TIBCO EMS, use the "tibjmsnaming://" prefix. Below an example to load a factory named 'ConnectionFactory'. The advantage of this code is that it's independent of the implementation.

```
        // provider-specific code
        String providerContextFactory = "com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory";
        String providerUrl = "tibjmsnaming://localhost:51515";
        String cfName = "ConnectionFactory";

        // JMS generic code
        Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, providerContextFactory);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);

        if (userName != null) {
           env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
           if (password != null)
              env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        }

        InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(env);

        ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup(cfName);
```

Comment: Hi Axel, sorry for the late reply. In your example, what would "providerContextFactory" be?

Comment: This is the name of the 'ConnectionFactory-Factory'. For TIBCO EMS it would be the String "com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory". For Solace "com.solacesystems.jndi.SolJNDIInitialContextFactory", for ActiveMQ "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"

Comment: sorry for my incomplete example earlier - I've made some changes now